# Regular expression matching DNS

Tags: regex, dns

Simplified issue (Extendable if requested): I'm running a chat, and don't want people to spam DNS's on it. Therefore, I need a regex which can check for dns's being written on the chat, and stop them. ONLY DNS's, nothing else which may resemble a dns, but could actually be a command being executed or someone just talking. (By the way, I already have normal IP's well covered)

So I found this DNS's matching regex which is the one I apply now for censoring:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?(\.|dot|\(dot\)|-|;|:|,)\s(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me|io)\b
```

It works for stopping DNS's. However, it's also censoring users typing in commands such as: /email add email@mail.com email@mail.com (A command commonly typed in on my chat, which the dns regex confuses as a dns)
Or sometimes just when someone types something containing many dots, and maybe ending in one such ending as the ones within the final regex parenthesis.

Therefore, what I need is a more precise dns matching regex, which will detect DNS's, and ONLY DNS's. However, my regex knowledge is very limited. I would really appreciate help with this!

Comment: For email addresses, try prepending `(^|[^@a-zA-Z0-9\-\.])` to your regex. The last point I think is not completely solvable. Doing this kind of check has drawbacks (i.e. false positives) that you cannot avoid. Anyway, one thing you can do is to use a set of white words. Is there any false positive example that you are aware of?

Comment: False positives are kinda rare, when It happens I don't tend to be paying too much attention to them. But I'm pretty sure it's just normal chatting with too many dots.

I think limiting the ammount of characters on the center domain argument between the two dots, would allow for the regex to work better. I really doubt someone is going to spam a really long domain, and I think that would fix the normal talking circunstances.

I will also prepend the section of regex code for the email cases.

Comment: So at the moment it's looking like this including the email check:
`(^|[^@a-zA-Z0-9\-\.])[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?(\.|dot|\(dot\)|-|;|:|,)\s(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me|io)\b`
I would actually have to limit the number of characters on each section of the dns check so that regex doesn't confuse normal chatting.
(I have a whitelist for stuff I don't mind by the way, so that's not an issue.)

Comment: Your regexp is missing 1533 top-level domains (as of this writing, more may have been delegated when you read this).

Comment: I applied the full regex as suggested by @horcrux, however, people adding their email through a command are still being detected as though they are sending a dns.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl I doubt any of those 1533 dns's would be sent on my minecraft server's chat. People usually send other server's dns's, which is the only thing I wish to stop.